# Fastest way to rank items with multiple values and weightings

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a collection of key value pairs like this:

```
{ 
   'key1': [value1_1, value2_1, value3_1, ...], 
   'key2': [value1_2, value2_2, value3_2, ...],
   ...
 }
```

and also a list which is in the same order as the values list, which contains the weight each variable should have applied. So it looks like `[weight_1, weight_2, weight_3, ...]`.

My goal is to end up with an ordered list of keys in accordance to which has the highest overall score of values. Note that the values aren't all standardized / normalized, so value1_x could range from 1 - 10 but value 2_x could range from 1 - 100000. This has been the tricky part for me as I have to normalize the data somehow.

I'm trying to make this algorithm run to scale for many different values, so it would take the same amount of time for 1 or for 100 (or at least logarithmically more time). Is that possible? Is there any really efficient way I can go about this?

Comment: You can't avoid linear time complexity since normalizing and summing requires you to work with all values.

Comment: @Keyser: Well it's theoretically possible there is some tricky data structure that, given a list of weights, gives you the top k items according to the given weight distribution in sublinear time. I don't have high hopes there is.

Comment: Of course you'd need linear preprocessing time, but that can be amortized if there are enough queries to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get linear-time, but you can do it faster; this looks like a matrix-multiply to me, so I suggest you use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

values = np.matrix([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]
])

weights = np.matrix([[10., 20., 30., 40.]]).transpose()

res = (values * weights).transpose().tolist()[0]

items = zip(res, keys)
items.sort(reverse=True)
```

which gives

```
[(330.0, 'key3'), (230.0, 'key2'), (130.0, 'key1')]
```

**Edit:** with [thanks to @Ondro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122856/numpy-how-to-sort-an-array-of-value-key-pairs-in-descending-order#22124985) for np.dot and [to @unutbu for np.argsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122856/numpy-how-to-sort-an-array-of-value-key-pairs-in-descending-order#22122985), here is an improved version entirely in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# set up values
keys = np.array(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
values = np.array([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],    # values1_x
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],    # values2_x
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]     # values3_x
])
weights = np.array([10., 20., 30., 40.])

# crunch the numbers
res = np.dot(values, -weights)   # negative of weights!

order = res.argsort(axis=0)  # sorting on negative value gives
                             # same order as reverse-sort; there does
                             # not seem to be any way to reverse-sort
                             # directly
sortedkeys = keys[order].tolist()
```

which results in `['key3', 'key2', 'key1']`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a normalization function, that will linearly transform your values into [0,1]

```
def normalize(val, ilow, ihigh, olow, ohigh):
    return ((val-ilow) * (ohigh-olow) / (ihigh - ilow)) + olow
```

Now, use `normalize` to compute a new dictionary with normalized values. Then, sort by the weighted sum:

```
def sort(d, weights, ranges):
    # ranges is a list of tuples containing the lower and upper bounds of the corresponding value

    newD = {k:[normalize(v,ilow, ihigh, 0, 1) for v,(ilow, ihigh) in zip(vals, ranges)] for k,val in d.iteritems()}  # d.items() in python3
    return sorted(newD, key=lambda k: sum(v*w for v,w in zip(newD[k], weights)))
```