# Numpy - how to sort an array of value/key pairs in descending order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was looking at the problem [Fastest way to rank items with multiple values and weightings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122173/fastest-way-to-rank-items-with-multiple-values-and-weightings) and came up with the following solution, but with two remaining issues:

```
import numpy as np

# set up values
keys = np.array([
    ['key1'],
    ['key2'],
    ['key3']
])
values = np.matrix([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]
])
weights = np.matrix([10., 20., 30., 40.]).transpose()

# crunch the numbers
res = values * weights

# combine results with labels
items = np.hstack((np.array(res), keys))

# !First problem - .hstack has promoted the first column from float64 to S4:
# array([['130.', 'key1'],
#        ['230.', 'key2'],
#        ['330.', 'key3']], 
#       dtype='|S4')
# How can I force it to stay numeric?

items.sort(reverse=True)   # doesn't work, no 'reverse' argument

# !Second problem - how to sort the array in descending order?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `argsort` method of numpy arrays to sort keys with indices that would sort other array.

```
import numpy as np

# set up values
keys = np.array([
    ['key1'],
    ['key2'],
    ['key3']
])
values = np.array([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]
])
weights = np.array([10., 20., 30., 40.])

# crunch the numbers
res = np.dot(values, weights)

sortedkeys = keys[res.argsort(axis=0)[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could merge `res` and `keys` into a structured array:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions
items = recfunctions.merge_arrays([res,keys])
```

Since `np.sort` does not have a `reverse=True` flag, I think the best you can do is reverse the returned array, (e.g. `items[::-1]`) or else take the negative of `res`:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions

# set up values
keys = np.array([
    ['key1'],
    ['key2'],
    ['key3']
])
values = np.matrix([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]
])
weights = np.matrix([10., 20., 30., 40.]).transpose()

# crunch the numbers
res = values * weights

# combine results with labels
res = np.asarray(-res)
items = recfunctions.merge_arrays([res,keys])
items.dtype.names = ['res', 'key']
items.sort(order=['res'])
print(items)
```

yields

```
[(-330.0, 'key3') (-230.0, 'key2') (-130.0, 'key1')]
```

Note that `refunctions.merge_arrays` is just a Python convenience function. It uses `zip` and `np.fromiter`. It would definitely be faster to avoid joining `res` and `keys` and instead use `argsort` to find the indices that sort `res` and use those to reorder `keys`:

```
import numpy as np

# set up values
keys = np.array([
    ['key1'],
    ['key2'],
    ['key3']
])
values = np.matrix([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]
])
weights = np.matrix([10., 20., 30., 40.]).transpose()

# crunch the numbers
res = values * weights

# combine results with labels
res = np.squeeze(np.asarray(res))
idx = np.argsort(res)[::-1]
print(keys[idx])
print(res[idx])
```

yields

```
[['key3']
 ['key2']
 ['key1']]
[ 330.  230.  130.]
```

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @ondro and @unutbu, here is what I finally ended up with:

```
import numpy as np

# set up values
keys = np.array(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
values = np.array([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],    # values1_x
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],    # values2_x
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]     # values3_x
])
weights = np.array([10., 20., 30., 40.])

# crunch the numbers
res = np.dot(values, -weights)   # negative of weights!

order = res.argsort(axis=0)  # sorting on negative value gives
                             # same order as reverse-sort; there does
                             # not seem to be any way to reverse-sort
                             # directly
sortedkeys = keys[order].tolist()
```

which returns `['key3', 'key2', 'key1']` (keys, sorted in reverse order by dot-product of values and weights).