# numpy sort a structured array by two fields, ascending and descending orders

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have this line of code:

```
TableArr = numpy.sort(TableArr, order=['destID','ATTRACT'])
```

I need the `'ATTRACT'` order to be descending while the destID to be ascending, which is default for both. Attempts with `[::-1]` failed, as it reverses the entire array.

I'll add that a `reverse` argument that can be set to `True` or `False` was mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122173/fastest-way-to-rank-items-with-multiple-values-and-weightings), but it doesn't work for me and isn't mentioned in the Numpy's [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).

Comment: I assume `TableArr` is a numpy record array? You're probably better of using pandas: its `DataFrame` class has a [sort method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) that can do what you want.

Comment: The Python list sort takes a `reverse` parameter; numpy's does not.  The numpy solution in the link was to multiply a column by -1, and argsort.

Comment: If @hpauli's approach doesn't work for you, you could sort by `'destID'`, and then sort slices with the same values in this field independently by `'ATTRACT'` and replace the slices. This might be slow though. Or you convert to a list and use the `key`-argument of `list.sort`

Comment: @hpauli's Thanks for the tip, I simply multiplied that 'ATTRACT' column by (-1) before and after the sort. Thanks all the others as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an interactive session that tests the idea in my comment:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: dt = np.dtype([('destID',int),('ATTRACT',float),('other','S10')])
In [3]: TableArr=np.zeros((10,),dt)
In [5]: TableArr['destID']=np.random.randint(10,size=(10,))
In [6]: TableArr['ATTRACT']=np.random.randint(100,size=(10,))

In [7]: TableArr
Out[7]: 
array([(2, 39.0, b''), (7, 7.0, b''), (8, 74.0, b''), (5, 83.0, b''),
       (5, 3.0, b''), (9, 26.0, b''), (8, 9.0, b''), (3, 1.0, b''),
       (1, 67.0, b''), (7, 5.0, b'')], 
      dtype=[('destID', '<i4'), ('ATTRACT', '<f8'), ('other', 'S10')])

In [13]: Tcopy=TableArr[['destID','ATTRACT']].copy()
# use copy() to avoid a FutureWarning

In [14]: Tcopy['ATTRACT'] *= -1  # 'reverse' a field

In [16]: I=np.argsort(Tcopy,order=['destID','ATTRACT'])

In [17]: I
Out[17]: array([8, 0, 7, 3, 4, 1, 9, 2, 6, 5], dtype=int32)

In [18]: TableArr[I]
Out[18]: 
array([(1, 67.0, b''), (2, 39.0, b''), (3, 1.0, b''), (5, 83.0, b''),
       (5, 3.0, b''), (7, 7.0, b''), (7, 5.0, b''), (8, 74.0, b''),
       (8, 9.0, b''), (9, 26.0, b'')], 
      dtype=[('destID', '<i4'), ('ATTRACT', '<f8'), ('other', 'S10')])
```

The integers are increasing, and for the 3 cases where they tie, the floats are decreasing.  So it works.